# change font size of button with change in button size

Tags: asp.net

i want to auto adjust button font according to button size 
such as with the change in browser size, button size change but text size not change want to change font size for this in asp.net
Any help

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean an HTML button?

You could try this in your stylesheet:

```
<style>
    button {
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: [link](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for more info. *Note this is from 2012.

Comment: by this i am getting a very large view i want text size to adjust with button size as button size decrease with decrease in browser size